# String arrays in angular 2 and mongodb

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, angular, typescript

I'm confused with string arrays using angular 2 and mongodb.

my class

```
import { CollectionObject } from './collection-object.model';

export interface Prox extends CollectionObject{
  location_id: string;
  nearby_locations: string[];
}
```

After inserting, my mongo looks like this

```
{ "_id" : "9JrBYBCmPSZ7PLpt7", "location_id" : "1", "nearby_locations" : [ { "location" : "2" }, { "location" : "3" } ] }
{ "_id" : "ha7CRD35pXwBkN4Cx", "location_id" : "2", "nearby_locations" : [ { "location" : "1" }, { "location" : "3" } ] }
{ "_id" : "zLTpYGYWguv9gbnCC", "location_id" : "3", "nearby_locations" : [ { "location" : "2" }, { "location" : "1" } ] }
```

How do I retrieve and looping through nearby_locations?
this doesn't work:

```
let myprox = Proxs.findOne({});
for (let map of myprox.nearby_locations)
 {
alert(map);
//map is an object, not a string!
 }
```

the following code does work, but visual studio will complain there is an error because 'location' is not defined in my type script.

```
let myprox = Proxs.findOne({});
for (let map of myprox.nearby_locations)
 {
alert(map.location);
 }
```

Is there a more correct way of doing it so that visual studio doesnt complain?

Comment: Can you show what you retrieve when calling `alert(JSON.stringify(map));`?

Comment: it shows {"location":"2"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
let myprox = Proxs.findOne({}) as Prox;
myprox.nearby_locations.forEach(obj => {
    console.log(obj.location);
});
```

---

#### Edit

My bad.
Your definition isn't correct, it should be:

```
export interface Prox extends CollectionObject {
  location_id: string;
  nearby_locations: { location: string }[];
}
```

Or another way to write the same thing:

```
interface Location {
    location: string;
}

export interface Prox extends CollectionObject {
  location_id: string;
  nearby_locations: Location[];
}
```

Or a third way:

```
type Location = {
    location: string;
}

export interface Prox extends CollectionObject {
  location_id: string;
  nearby_locations: Location[];
}
```

Comment: this is similar to my 2nd block of code. it works, but visual studio complains that 'location' does not exist on type string.

Comment: works like a charm! thanks! any online tutorial or article that shows what you just shared?

Comment: It wasn't anything special, it's exactly as declaring it as new interface. Check my updated answer

Comment: wouldnt the 2nd and 3rd way nest my "location" further into Prox.nearby_locations.location.location?

Comment: Nope. They are equivalent to: `nearby_locations: { location: string }[]`

Answer (score -1):

try this i think it will help you:

```
alert(map[0].location);
```